# memcache and a custom DoFn with dataflow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use google memcache with dataflow.  I'd like essentially like to transform data into memcache.  Is it possible to use the google memcache api inside of dataflow?

I get the following error:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:        `com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'memcache' or call 'Set()' was not found. com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.setExceptionResult(FutureWrapper.java:65)`

This is the line of code:

```
AsyncMemcacheService asyncCache =     MemcacheServiceFactory.getAsyncMemcacheService("namespace");
asyncCache.put("key", "value", Expiration.byDeltaSeconds(100000)).get();
```

Comment: Are you trying to use an appengine library? That seems problematic because the appengine runtime isn't available in Dataflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/memcache) is part of App Engine and not directly accessible outside of App Engine. As a result you won't be able to access it from Dataflow directly. What you could do is create an App Engine service that acted as a proxy and send requests to that from Dataflow.

Comment: That's interesting given that the Dataflow [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq) mentions dataflow as one option for sharing data between pipelines :-)

Comment: Memcache is now available in dataflow through GAE RemoteAPI.